# 404 Error for Custom Post type 

Tags: 404-error

I have a function on my theme ("dancefloor" by "Gorilla Themes") that allows me to make a post in a section in my dashboard called Events *(Custom post Type)*.

If you schedule the date to anytime in the future it will show up in the 
Events widget or on the Events Page. That all work fine and Dandy.

> But when you click on the link or excerpt, it give a `404` error. Anyone know why this might be happening?

[Live Example here](http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/absinthe/events/).

Comment: re-save your permalink structure, and see if works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps I take that back ... you must be changing stuff at the same time as i was writing this .. so this answer may not be any help

at first it seemed the URL's were wrong

the title url is linking to `events` the read more is linking to `event`

eg ..

http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/absinthe/event/dead-divine-farewell-tour/

and

http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/absinthe/event/dead-divine-farewell-tour/

Comment: I did notice that, just not sure how to rectify

Comment: @greg now both links are going to 404 ... can you go and reset your Permalinks to DEFAULT and check it goes away?